# Using AJAX to dynamically change data from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to change the opacity of my graph bars dynamically. I have them currently telling the user to refresh the page which I don't want. How could I use AJAX to achieve something like this?

```
const opacitySlider = document.getElementById('opacity');

$('#opacity').on('input', function () {
    $('.bars').css('opacity', $(this).val());
    localStorage.setItem('opacity', opacitySlider.value);
    checkAlert.innerHTML = 'Please click the refresh button or reload the page to make new changes.';
});
```

Comment: Add some more code, and detail to your question. I almost understand what you want to do, but it's not clear. For fear of downvote hell and no help, please update your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want, as `$('.bars').css('opacity', $(this).val());` should change the `opacity` if `$(this).val()` has a value between `0 and 1`.

but if you want to make the change from ajax you just have to use the jQuery ajax function like

```
$('#opacity').on('input', function () {
    $('.bars').css('opacity', $(this).val());
    localStorage.setItem('opacity', opacitySlider.value);
        });
    $.ajax({
            url : '/your/url',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                    //assuming you're retrieving the opacity from server
                    $('.bars').css('opacity', response.opacity);
            }
    })
```